# Poor Alignment of Series on Chart

Tags: vb.net

I have the following code which I am using to create a chart on a window form.  It is working as expected but with one exception.  One of the series is not aligned on the x-axis.  What am I doing wrong?.  I have tried to insert an alignment instruction but that simply leads to error.  I cant figure this out.  I have pasted my code and the relevant datagridview that the chart looks at and the chart that I have.

Dim dtoverview As DataTable = New DataTable

```
    dtoverview.Columns.Add("col1", GetType(String))
    dtoverview.Columns.Add("col2", GetType(String))
    dtoverview.Columns.Add("col3", GetType(String))

    Dim z As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount
    Dim row As Integer = 0
    For row = 0 To z - 1

        dtoverview.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Item(1, row).Value, DataGridView1.Item(0, row).Value, DataGridView1.Item(2, row).Value)
    Next

    Dim dv As DataView = New DataView(dtoverview)
    'dv.Sort = "col2 asc"

    Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(1)
    Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0)
    Chart1.DataManipulator.FilterSetEmptyPoints = True
    Chart1.DataManipulator.FilterMatchedPoints = True

    Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(dv, "col3", "col2", "col1", "Label=col1")

    For Each cs As Series In Chart1.Series
        Chart1.DataManipulator.Filter(DataVisualization.Charting.CompareMethod.EqualTo, 0, cs)
        Chart1.Series(0).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
        Chart1.Series(1).ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn
    Next

    dv = Nothing
    dtoverview = Nothing
    releaseObject(dv)
    releaseObject(dtoverview)

End Sub
```

My goal for this code is for the value of 149 (in orange) to be on top of the 440 column and the value of 56 to sit on to of the 120 column.  The attached doc shows the current chart and the table that the code is getting data from.

[image: current chart and table]

Comment: Not sure exactly but your for loop looks a little odd. Are you meaning to refer to Series(0),Series(1) instead of cs?

Comment: I am but when I refer to series by number it throws n exception. This loop works to a point but I can't work out where I need to amend it to make the series align.